# How would you say, "Why can't I have them both?"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, english-to-japanese

I've been looking at the structure of sentences like "They're both cute" and "I want this one" 「どちら」 and 「どっち」 meaning which one but how would I say the following:

> "I don't know what I want"

And

> "Why can't I have them both" / "Can't I have them both"

Thank you!

Comment: I think どちり is a typo — maybe for どちら?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/s4eamxv.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

> どちらも　どっちも neither
>
> どちらでも　どっちでも both

would be appropriate for the respective cases.

> どちらも好き。 I like neither.
>
> どっちでも欲しい。 I want both.

Just as in a conversation:

> どっちが食べたい？どっちでも美味しそうだから好きに選んで。
>
> Which do you want to eat? Both seem delicious so choose what you want.

So if you want to go for both, why not go with:

> どっちでも欲しいから買ってね？ I want both, so buy them (for me) okay?

Comment: どちらも好き means "I like both", not "I like neither". The latter would have to be something like どちらも好き**じゃない**.

Comment: Thanks, that is quite useful but if it wasn't purchasing but more like a decision such as which clothes you wanted to wear or something, how would you say "can't I HAVE them both"? Thanks!

Comment: 「どちら**で**も どっち**で**も both」「どっち**で**も欲しい。I want both.」「どっち**で**も美味しいそう Both seem delicious」「どっち**で**も欲しいから I want both, so」 <-- "both" の場合は「どちらも どっちも」「どっちも/どちらも欲しい」「どっちも/どちらも美味しそう」「どっちも欲しい」だと思いますが・・・。(「どちらでも」「どっちでも」 would be more like "either"... eg: 「どちらでもいい。/ どっちでもいい。」"Either is fine." cf: 「どちらもいい。/どっちもいい。」 "Both are good.")

Answer (score 1):

First, some basic examples:

> どちらとも欲｛ほ｝しい / どちらも欲｛ほ｝しい / 両方｛りょうほう｝欲｛ほ｝しい I want both
>
> どちらも欲しくない / 両方とも欲しくない I don't want either / I want neither
>
> どちらでもいい Whichever one is fine どちらでも欲しい I want either one (sounds strange)

As for your specific questions:

> "I don't know what I want" どっちを選んだらいいかわからない (I don't know which I should choose)
>
> "Why can't I have them both?" どうして両方もらえないですか？
>
> "Can't I have them both?" 両方もらえないの？